# Debug a Flask (Python) web application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do I configure Visual Studio Code to debug a Flask (Python) web application?

For example, when I set the debugger in the view function, it should allow me to step through that function when we hit that route in the browser.

I have already installed the Python extension in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: please check out the following site, hopefully that'll help resolve the issue. https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/wiki/Debugging:-Flask

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is my configuration for Flask 0.12, Python 3.6, and Visual Studio Code 1.20

```
// File "launch.json"
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.py",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run"
            ],
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

# app.py file
app.run(port=5000)
# Don't use debug=True, because it disables the Visual Studio Code debugger
# app.run(port=5000, debug=True) - disables the Visual Studio Code debugger
```

Comment: The don't use *debug=True* tip is very valuable.  Thanks for your answer!

Comment: thank you for the _debug=True_ part, @Vlad! I was struggling with this for a bit. I was having trouble finding this in the docs as well but maybe I just didn't read far enough..

Comment: Just curious: if you update the code, and refresh the corresponding page, does the content gets updated? Or do you need to restart the flask server in VScode?

Answer (score 7):

I found the following solution working for me. I followed the official tutorial with some tweaks in the generated *launch.json* file.

[Visual Studio Code official flask tutorial debugging section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_run-the-app-in-the-debugger)

My setup is:

- Python 3.8.3
- Flask 1.1.2
- Visual Studio Code 1.46.0

My current *launch.json* file is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"  // make sure it is not "0"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
               // "--no-debugger", Comment out this line
               // "--no-reload"  Comment out this line
            ],
            "jinja": true
        }
    ]
}
```

By default the generated *launch.json* file had the

- "FLASK_DEBUG": "0"
- "--no-debugger"
- "--no-reload"

lines, which prevented me from debugging.

Answer (score 3):

I don't use Visual Studio Code for Python development. However, Flask has a really nice debugging option, that allows you to debug from a browser. This is not a solution for Visual Studio Code, but a workaround.

When you define your application, pass the `debug = true` parameter to enable debugging mode. Then you can debug your code from the browser.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
```

More information can be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/config/).

Comment: I know what VS is. I used it when it was beta, and the only ability of it was intellisense. Check this: https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode

Comment: Yes I have already installed this plug-in but I am not able to find a way to debug my views in python even if I set debugger on view function it doesn't stops when I hit that view url in browser

Comment: When debugging using Visual Studio Code and the python extension, please remove the lines ```app.config['Debug'] = True```.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create `startup.py` in your project root directory with the following code

   ```
    # Needed to start the debugger for the Flask application in the Visual Studio Code IDE
    import sys
    import re
    from flask.cli import main
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
   ```
2. Update the `launch.json` file in Visual Studio Code by browsing to the *Debug* tab (Left pane), and then click on the settings icon (Gear icon). Scroll down to the "FLASK" section:

   a) Change `"program"` value to `"${workspaceRoot}/startup.py"`

   b) Change `"FLASK_APP"` value to `"${workspaceRoot}/run.py"` (or whatever your main entry point file is"
3. Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*, and then click on **workspace settings** in the top right corner. Insert the following field:  `"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/Scripts/python.exe"` (If your virtual environment is named something other than `venv` then replace it with the appropriate value.)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has added a tutorial to create the launch configuration for Flask debugging: *[Flask Tutorial -> Run the app in the debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask#_run-the-app-in-the-debugger)*

So briefly, you must have a section like:

```
{
    "name": "Python: Flask",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "flask",
    "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
    },
    "args": [
        "run",
        "--no-debugger",
        "--no-reload"
    ],
    "jinja": true
},
```

In the `launch.json` file, where the *app.py* file is your Flask application runner file. After that you must select the proper configuration setting in the dropdown menu of Visual Studio Code. Kind of this:

[image: The Selector!]

After that, just hit <kbd>F5</kbd> and start your "journey"!

Answer (score 1):

We can use [the first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056448/debug-a-flask-python-web-application-in-visual-studio-code/42911885#42911885) to Linux (**Ubuntu**) as well with the modifications below.

In Visual Studio Code, add the configuration for Flask debug. Which you will get from the add button. And it will look like below.

```
{
    "name": "Flask",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "stopOnEntry": false,
    "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
    "program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.py", # Your start .py file
    "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}/app.py" # Your start .py file
    },
    "args": [
        "run"
        // --no-debug and one more line removed.
    ],
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "debugOptions": [
        "RedirectOutput"
    ]
}
```

Step 2. Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings*, and then click on the *workspace settings* tab in the top right corner. Insert the following field: `"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}/venv/bin/python2.7",` (If your virtual environment is named something other than venv then replace it with the appropriate value.)

Comment: Re *"In Visual Studio Code, add the configuration for Flask debug"*: How exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To further extend on [the answer from Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056448/debug-a-flask-python-web-application-in-visual-studio-code/42911885#42911885), I had to configure a debugger for Visual Studio Code in a Windows environment with [Anaconda 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaconda_(Python_distribution)). I did so by using the following:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda2\\envs\\neuralnets\\python.exe"
}
```

with *neuralnets* being my Anaconda 2 virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), make sure you have your [virtual environment configured in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

> For general debugging features such as inspecting variables, setting
> breakpoints, and other activities that aren't language-dependent,
> review [Visual Studio Code
> debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

Your `launch.json` file should look something like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Flask",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
      "module": "flask.cli",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "env": {
        "FLASK_APP": "sample",
        "LC_ALL": "en_US.utf-8",
        "LANG": "en_US.utf-8"
      },
      "args": [
        "run",
        "--no-debugger",
        "--no-reload"
      ],
      "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
      "debugOptions": [
        "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
        "WaitOnNormalExit",
        "RedirectOutput"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Set the `FLASK_APP` environment variable to the name of your application file.

Set `--no-debugger` to avoid any potential conflicts with the [Werkzeug debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/werkzeug/info).

Comment: I tried this, but somehow debugger would not stop at the breakpoint. I wonder if this needs to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that when I would first run the flask app and then hit the debugger button, it would say the port is already in use or nothing would seem to happen at all or the debugger would not stop at the set breakpoint.
I tried every single solution here, and none of them seems to work, so I just followed the official guide on vscode website, and it actually works! So take a look here,
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask. If you scroll down a little bit, you'll see how to set up the debugger for flask app using vscode debugger.
The trick is that you somehow don't need to 'run' the server while debugging because if you did, then the running server is occupying that port and the debugging would not appear to be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a venv folder, you need to activate it before running the Flask server. To do this, use the [preLaunchTask](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_can-a-background-task-be-used-as-a-prelaunchtask-in-launchjson) option. The task is declared inside `.vscode/tasks.json`.

`.vscode/launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "flask",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "app.py",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development",
                "FLASK_DEBUG": "1"
            },
            "preLaunchTask": "activate_venv",
            "args": [
                "run"
            ],
            "jinja": true,
            "python": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python"
        }
    ],
}
```

`.vscode/task.json`:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "activate_venv",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "source ./venv/bin/activate",
        }
    ]
}
```