# Debug flask app in visual studio code on windows

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug python flask app from VSCode using the [VSCode-Python](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python) extension. According two the documentation there are 2 ways to make it work:

- Use the `"module":"flask.cli"` option in launch.json
- Use a startup script, which imports `flask.cli` module. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39056448/debug-flaskpython-web-application-in-visual-studio-code)

For both ways I end up with: `OSError: Windows error 1`. That seems to be an error indicating that the `main` function imported from `flask.cli` does not exists.

I am using virtualenv. If I try to run from command line, the application works fine.

Here is the settings.json content (env is the folder which contains the environment scripts):

```
{
  "python.pythonPath": "${workspaceRoot}\\backend\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

And here is the launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Flask (0.11.x or later)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "module":"flask.cli",
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}\\backend\\app.py"
            },
            "args": [
                "run",
                "--no-debugger",
                "--no-reload"
            ],
            "debugOptions": [
                "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
                "WaitOnNormalExit",
                "RedirectOutput"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the complete error stack trace:

```
runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'flask.cli' found in sys.modules after import of package 'flask', but prior to execution of 'flask.cli'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
line 205, in run_module return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
line 96, in _run_module_code mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
line 85, in _run_code exec(code, run_globals)
line 517, in <module> main(as_module=True)
line 513, in main cli.main(args=args, prog_name=name)
line 380, in main return AppGroup.main(self, *args, **kwargs)
line 707, in main e.show()
line 47, in show echo(self.ctx.get_usage() + '\n', file=file, color=color)
line 259, in echo file.write(message)
line 180, in write return self._text_stream.write(x)
line 164, in write raise OSError(self._get_error_message(GetLastError()))
OSError: Windows error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Flask app",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": false,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "env": {
            "FLASK_APP": "${workspaceRoot}\\backend\\app.py"
        },
        "args": [
            "run",
            "--no-debugger",
            "--no-reload"
        ],
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    }
],
"compounds": []
}
```

I think you should remove "module": "flask.cli" because it did not work for me

Comment: I didn't test our approach. I have managed to make it work with flask.cli after all, the error was just that I was pointing to a wrong python file. The error message confused me a lot