# python flask in VS Code dont stop at breakpoint

Tags: python

i walk through this tutorial:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask

I use windows 10 and a python 3.7.64bit in virtualenv for training.

Problem: The breakpoint remains ignored...

I already changed the the json settings like mentioned in the tutorial. Also i tried some different solutions i've found, like:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42911885/10514935

May somebody have the same issue and found a working solution?

Regards

Comment: Does it have to be VS Code? You can go through this doc: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Comment: Nope, i already start webdevelopment and i'm not fixed at any IDE... what would u suggest?